# Is it possible to transfer a file to USB device using libusb?

Tags: file-transfer, libusb

I am trying to transfer the file via libusb to the USB device (pendrive). I have seen submit_bulk_transfer function in libusb-1.0.6 package. If there is a way to transfer the file then can you please suggest me. I want to transfer the file not as raw data.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you will need to implement Mass Storage, SCSI, and the file system that is used on the device in order to do so, which is a *lot* of work, and it is already done by the USB and FS drivers of all desktop (and many other) OSs.

See [libusb FAQ](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/FAQ#CanIuselibusbtoopenafileonaUSBstoragedevice).

BTW `submit_bulk_transfer` is a very low level functionality of USB, related to many device classes, not only Mass Storage.

Comment: I am using 0x86 machine with linux kernel. Here I already have class drivers, scsi and file system. So with help of already existing functionalities can I achieve file transfer?

Comment: Hi, Geek. Yes, linux kernel has everything, but when using libusb you are leaving all kernel support out: to use `submit_bulk_transfer` you need to detach (disable) kernel usb driver, so you either has one or another.